# Which hook will allow me to change links in a page?

Tags: hooks

Which hook would allow me to change each link (given in `<a>` tags) in content pages and menus and change their attributes?

I need to implement this in a theme that uses Olivero as parent theme and the obvious `MYTHEME_preprocess_links()` results in a blank white screen (WSOD).

The only hook I've been able to use to change the page content is this one.

```php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables): void {
    $content = $variables['items'][0]['content'] ?? false;
    $type = $content['#type'] ?? '';

    if ($content && $type === 'processed_text') {
        $dom = new DomDocument();

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($variables['items'][0]['content']['#text']);
        $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        libxml_clear_errors();

        if (count($errors) === 0) {
            $edited = 0;

            foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We need to see your code to have the possibility to understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question. :) In this case I'm not certain I have code to share. I've simply been trying a bunch of theme hooks to see which get triggered and which actually give me access to the <a> tags within page contents. I must have tried 50 variations of hooks. I won't be able to remember them all.

Comment: Depending on what you are doing, it might be better to create an input filter.  This will affect the content wherever it is displayed in that filter, but it might be a more robust solution than using a hook in your theme.

Comment: There is no single "preprocesses all links everywhere" hook. Links in content are mostly field templates (use hook_preprocess_field) or editorial text (use a text filter). If not covered by those two, you have to look for module-specific hooks (like hook_preprocess_menu from menu module). Those are usually documented in MODULE_NAME.api.php of the module

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to the commenters I was able to figure out how to edit the DOM in content pages and menus.

Regarding version: **Drupal 10**.

*Replace "MYTHEME" with the machine name of your theme. Open your `MYTHEME.info.yml` file to see the name of your theme. It is case-sensitive.*

Within your `/themes/MYTHEME/` directory you may have a `MYTHEME.theme` file wherein you are able to declare hook functions. These hooks include those that allow you to preprocess data before it gets build into a template. It is here that you are able to adjust the HTML strings to your needs.

These hooks include a `$variables` parameter that will eat up all of your available memory if you try to print it via `var_dump`.

## Editing content

Content includes those that you build in `/admin/content` and those you build in `/admin/structure/block/block-content`.

The hook used to adjust the HTML of content pages is `MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables)`.

Inspect `$variables['entity_type']` to determine if you are editing content or block-content.

The HTML string that will be used to build your content is in `$variables['items'][0]['content']['#text']`. Adjust that string via string manipulation or DOM manipulation with [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) then overwrite `$variables['items'][0]['content']['#text']` with your edited string.

If using DOMDocument you may need to ignore all errors generated by loadHTML() because this feature does not understand HTML5 elements, but it can still work with them.

```php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables): void {
    $content = $variables['items'][0]['content'] ?? false;
    $type = $content['#type'] ?? '';
    // Blocks are the pieces that are not content. These include the sidebar, search, header, and footer.
    $block = $variables['entity_type'] === 'block_content';

    if ($content && $type === 'processed_text') {
        $dom = new DomDocument();

        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $options = LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_NOERROR;
        $dom->loadHTML('<div>' . $content['#text'] . '</div>', $options);
        // Use this variable to inspect the errors when troubleshooting.
        // $errors = libxml_get_errors();
        libxml_clear_errors();

        $parsedHTML = $dom->saveHTML();

        // Errors are fine as long as the HTML string was successfully parsed by DOMDocument.
        if ($parsedHTML) {
            // Your code here to manipulate DOM.
        }
    }
}
```

## Editing menus

The hook used to adjust the HTML of menus is `MYTHEME_preprocess_menu(&$variables)`.

There are various menus in a Drupal page. These include `admin`, `main`, and `account`.

The menu items to adjust are within `$variables['items']`. The structure of each element within that array is:

```
items(array) 
 - menu_link_content:{unique_id}(array)
 -  - is_expanded(boolean)
 -  - is_collapsed(boolean)
 -  - in_active_trail(boolean)
 -  - attributes(object)
 -  - title(string) Sample menu item
 -  - url(object)
 -  - below(array)
 -  -  - menu_link_content:{unique_id}(array)
 -  -  -  - is_expanded(boolean)
 -  -  -  - is_collapsed(boolean)
 -  -  -  - in_active_trail(boolean)
 -  -  -  - attributes(object)
 -  -  -  - title(string) Sample sub-menu item
 -  -  -  - url(object)
 -  -  -  - below(array)
 -  -  -  - original_link(object)
```

Each menu item may have sub-items. These are saved in the `['below']` key as an array.

If you want to adjust the url the `['url']` element holds a Drupal URL object. Refer to [the documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/10) on how to adjust a Drupal URL object.

Here is an example to get you started:

```php
function adjustMenuItem($item) {
    // Your code to adjust the elements of the $item array.

    // Handle recursive array elements.
    if (isset($item['below']) && is_array($item['below']) && count($item['below']) > 0) {
        foreach ($item['below'] as $key => $value) {
            $item['below'][$key] = adjustMenuItem($value);
        }
    }

    return $item;
}

function MYTHEME_preprocess_menu(&$variables): void {
    $name = $variables['menu_name'] ?? '';

    if ($name === 'main' && is_array($variables['items'])) {
        foreach ($variables['items'] as $key => $value) {
            $variables['items'][$key] = adjustMenuItem($value);
        }
    }
}
```